# Extract sentence from text containing a specific phrase

Tags: php, regex

I have a text document with 2 sentences:

`stack overflow is the best. hello stack.`

(the dot at the end indicate the end of the sentence.)

how to extract the whole sentence from text if the sentence contain `the best`

and output the whole sentence which contains `the best`:

output: `stack overflow is the best.`

nothing tried. what regex should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would match the text which contain `best` upto the next literal dot.

```
(?:^|\.)\K.*?(?=best)[^\.]*\.
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fH1pV0/1)

Comment: HI @avinash-raj, it's nice. What if a word contains dot (`.`) before the final period?

Answer (score 3):

Prints all sentences containing `the best` w/o using regexes

```
$contents = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$sentences = explode('.',$contents);

foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
    if(false !== strpos($sentence,'the best'))
        print trim($sentence) . "\n";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/167890)

Comment: This assumes that '.' is the sole sentence delimiter.  And will incorrectly match non whole-word matches. eg: "the bestiality report" would get matched.